# How do I manipulate first table cell in table row based on values in second and third table cell

Tags: jquery

I would like to manipulate first table cell in a table row based on values in second and third table cell. This has to be done for each table row.

Is this possible with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tbl tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function() {
       var siblings = $(this).nextAll('td');
     $(this).html(siblings.eq(0).html() + siblings.eq(1).html());
    });
});
```

try it on this:

```
<table id="tbl">
 <tr>
   <td>one</td>
   <td>two</td>
   <td>three</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```